# Blank sheet when downloading xls using tabulator 4.2

Tags: tabulator

Using the 4.2 version of tabulator, I can get the xls doc to download but the contents (data) is missing. using table.download.

```
var table;
        function populateReport(url) {

            console.log("report generated. URL = " + url);
            table = new Tabulator("#ReportResults", {
                height: 500,
                pagination: "local",
                paginationSize: 25,
                index: "id",
                ajaxURL: url,
                columns:[
                    {title:"ID", field:"id", visible:"false",download:"false"},
                    {title:"Name", field:"UserFirstLastName", align:"left", formatter:"html"},
                    {title:"Email", field:"UserEmailAddress", align:"left", formatter:"html"},
                    {title:"Title", field:"UserTitle", align:"left", formatter:"html"},
                    {title:"Start Date", field:"UserStartDate", align:"left", formatter:"html"},
                    {title:"Last Activity", field:"UserLastActivity", align:"left", formatter:"html"},
                    {title:"Total Training", field:"UserTrainingTime", align:"left", formatter:"html"},
                    {title:"Manager", field:"ManagerFirstLastName", align:"left", formatter:"html"},
                    {title:"Series", field:"CourseSeriesName", align:"left", formatter:"html"},
                    {title:"Course", field:"CourseLibraryName", align:"left", formatter:"html"},
                    {title:"Assigned", field:"DateAssigned", align:"left", formatter:"html"},
                    {title:"Deadline", field:"AssignmentDeadline", align:"left", formatter:"html"},
                    {title:"Completed", field:"AssignmentCompletedDate", align:"left", formatter:"html"},
                    {title:"Score", field:"CourseScore", align:"center", formatter:"html"},
                    {title:"Group", field:"GroupName", align:"left", formatter:"html"},
                    {title:"Team", field:"TeamName", align:"left", formatter:"html"},
                    {title:"Catalog", field:"CatalogName", align:"left", formatter:"html"},
                ],
            });

            hideWrapper();
            $("#ReportPanel").slideDown();
            $('#DateLabel').show();
            console.log("report data displayed"); 

$("#download-xlsx").click(function () {
                table.download("xlsx", "data.xlsx", { sheetName: "MyData" });
                //$("#ReportResults").tabulator("download", "xlsx", "data.xlsx", { sheetName: "My Data" });
            });

            $('#ReportPanel').slideUp();
            $('#ReportResults').tabulator();
            $('#ReportResults').tabulator("destroy");
```

Any advice help would be appreciated..Using the 4.2 version of tabulator, I can get the xls doc to download but the contents (data) is missing. using table.download.

Comment: I had this issue and thought it was related to Ajax data. However, I finally found that it was something to do with the way I was setting groupBy. I added table.setGroupBy(false); prior to table.download(); to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Working Fine copy my example or edit your question and put real tabledata instead of Ajax URL

```js
const tabledata1 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Oli ",
    money: "0",
    col: "red",
    dob: ""
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Mary ",
    money: "0",
    col: "blue",
    dob: "14/05/1982"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Christine ",
    money: "0",
    col: "green",
    dob: "22/05/1982"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Brendon ",
    money: "0",
    col: "orange",
    dob: "01/08/1980"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Margret ",
    money: "0",
    col: "yellow",
    dob: "31/01/1999"
  },
];


const table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
           height: 500,
            pagination: "local",
            paginationSize: 25,
            index: "id",
  data: tabledata1, //assign data to table
  layout: "fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
  autoColumns: true
});

function myFunction() {
table.download("xlsx", "data.xlsx", {sheetName:"MyData"}); //download a Xlsx file that has a sheet name of "MyData"
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>


<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Download Excel</button>

  <div id="example-table"></div>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: My data is pulled via AJAX so the tabulator data grid is populated, once displayed I have the button to invoke the xls, this worked fine in the 3.2 version, I just can't get it to work in 4.2

Comment: The URL points to a JSON File which is built and saved on my server.

Comment: @PaulTimmerberg Did you do above Run Code snippet?

Comment: Yes, and it does work, but its not the implementation I am working with, appreciate the input.